# I keep getting this error in my django project and I have literally tried everything I could find on stackoverflow but nothing works

Tags: jquery, django, autocomplete

**Error:** Uncaught TypeError: $(...).autocomplete is not a function

**included in base.html:**

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
```

**autocomplete code reference:**
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/implement-search-autocomplete-for-input-fields-in-django/

**EDIT:**
its being used in a template where I have only one field and I have to show emails using the autocomplete feature. The template extends base.html

```
    {% block custom_js %}
        
     <script type="text/javascript">
     $( function() {
      var _emails = "{{ emails }}".split(',');
                    
      var availableTags = [];
        
      $.each(_emails, function(index, value){
             availableTags.push(value);
      });
                    
      $( "#id_email" ).autocomplete({
               source: availableTags
       });
        
       });
      </script>
      
{% endblock custom_js %}
```

Comment: Can you show more of your templates? where is this being called?

Comment: hi, I just edited the post. I hope I added what you asked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution for future reference:

I tried this and it worked for me.

https://forum.jquery.com/topic/uncaught-typeerror-catcomplete-is-not-a-function

***Changed function() to function($)*** as suggested in the answer in the forum. I haven't included jquery elsewhere yet this error wasn't resolving.